# How to npm publish specific folder but as package root

Tags: npm, package, node-modules, package.json

I have a project that include a gulp task for building and packaging the sources and release in a directory called `dist`. My goal is publish it as a npm package, but only my dist folder. The [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) says that I can use the `files` tag to specify files to export. It works. But, documentation also says that:

> If you name a folder in the array, then it will also include the files
>   inside that folder

The result, is a npm package, which node_modules looks like:

[image: generated npm package]

But I'd like to see all my files at the package's root (without that `dist` folder). My `index.js` file is inside the `dist` folder, but should be at root. I've tried to set tag `files` as `/dist/**/*` but it didn't work.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: I was able to build my project dist, then cd'ed into it to `npm publish`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are (and I recommend) using [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release), add the `pkgRoot` option in the `.releaserc.json` file. (You should also install [rjp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-json-property)):

```json
{
  "pkgRoot": "dist",
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    "@semantic-release/npm",
    [
      "@semantic-release/exec",
      {
        "prepareCmd": "npx rjp package.json version nextRelease.version"
      }
    ],
    [
      "@semantic-release/git",
      {
        "message": "Release <%= nextRelease.version %> [skip ci]",
        "assets": ["package.json", "CHANGELOG.md"]
      }
    ],
    "@semantic-release/changelog"
  ],
}
```

That'll take care of the problem. Just make sure your `dist` folder contains a `package.json` file. You can easily do that by adding a `cp` to your `postbuild` script:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "postbuild": "cp package.json dist"
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! An addition to this is the following. You can change the prepareCmd command to: `npm --no-git-tag-version version <%= nextRelease.version %>`. This will change the version in both package.json and package-lock.json. And by adding the `--no-git-tag-version` tag it will NOT create a git tag and NOT commit the files.

Comment: `cp`  isn't cross platform for your postbuild script

Comment: Any idea how to do this with `changesets`?

Answer (score 54):

I have the same desire but I think **there is no way of accomplishing this with only using npm tooling**. Another script/tool could be used to arrange your package.

#### Alternative Solution

Currently I am copying my `package.json` into the `dist` folder and then running `npm pack` inside the `dist` folder. I think this essentially provides the desired arrangement of our package.

Here is some relevant reading on this npm design: [Why no Directories.lib in Node](https://blog.izs.me/2013/02/why-no-directorieslib-in-node-the-less-snarky).

It's also interesting to note that jspm DOES respect the `directories.lib` option in `package.json` and rearranges the files when resolving the npm package.  This all has come about for me because I am wanting to build a common library which can be consumed by jspm or npm/webpack.

Comment: (Why no Directories.lib...) is a dead link

Comment: Why no Directories.lib in Node is saying, if you don't do it our way, you should feel pain. All this does is creates the need for tools to workaround this issue.

Comment: I believe this answer is outdated. As responses below note, using `npm pack`, the package.json `files` and `main` fields, and `.npmignore` gives a developer everything needed to create a package from a specific, installable directory.

Comment: Made some [scripts](https://gist.github.com/micimize/cebad5e0a7443374722b92cfed92f5a4) to streamline/enforce the "publish subdir" pattern

Comment: Can somebody post the solution how it can be achieved using npmignore, files and main property in package.json. I want to to move all file to the root and not have dist folder

Comment: (Why no Directories.lib...) The author's pitch "Doing an ugly thing should look ugly" is offending to all TypeScript developers and, in general, to all developers who use compilers. For years C++, .Net, Java developers were compiling their projects to lib/target/dist folders, and then JS community comes and calls this concept ugly, and that's why npm doesn't support it. Incredible. (no comment section there, so sorry for posting it here)

Comment: # .npmignore
\n **
\n !dist/**

Comment: @Jefftopia which answer?

Answer (score 46):

I have a similar problem to the original poster (@robsonrosa). In my case I use typecript which compiles to a `dist` directory. While I could make typescript compile to the root directory I think the best solution is to generate a separate `package.json` file in the dist directory.
This is similar to @scvnc suggestion of copying the `package.json` but with a twist:

*As part of the packaging process you should generate a `package.json` for the package which is based on but distinct from the main `package.json` file in the root directory*

The rationale:

- The root `package.json` file is the development file. It may contain scripts or development dependencies that are of no use to the package user, but may pose security concerns for you. Your packaging procedure may include code that strips that information from the production `package.json`.
- You may want to deploy your package to different environments which may require different package files (e.g. you may want to have different versions or dependencies).

--- EDIT ---

I was asked for a solution in the comments. So here is some code I am using. This should be considered as an example it is not meant to be generic and is specific to my projects.

My setup:

```
package.json         - main package.json with dev dependencies and useful scripts.
.npmignore           - files to ignore; copied to 'dist' directory as part of the setup.
/src                 - directory where my typescript code resides.
/src/SetupPackage.ts - bit of code used to setup the package.
/dist                - destination directory for the compiled javascript files.
```

I want to package only the `dist` directory and the directory should be the root directory in the package.

The file `SetupPackage.ts` in my `src` directory will be compiled to `SetupPackage.js` in the `dist` directory by typescript:

```
import fs from "fs";

// DO NOT DELETE THIS FILE
// This file is used by build system to build a clean npm package with the compiled js files in the root of the package.
// It will not be included in the npm package.

function main() {
    const source = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/../package.json").toString('utf-8');
    const sourceObj = JSON.parse(source);
    sourceObj.scripts = {};
    sourceObj.devDependencies = {};
    if (sourceObj.main.startsWith("dist/")) {
        sourceObj.main = sourceObj.main.slice(5);
    }
    fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/package.json", Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(sourceObj, null, 2), "utf-8") );
    fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/version.txt", Buffer.from(sourceObj.version, "utf-8") );

    fs.copyFileSync(__dirname + "/../.npmignore", __dirname + "/.npmignore");
}

main();
```

This file:

- Copies the root `package.json` but removes the scripts and dev dependencies which are not needed in the package. It also fixes the main entry point to the package.
- Writes the version of the package from `package.json` to a file called `version.txt`.
- Copies the `.npmignore` file from the root.

The .npmignore content is:

```
*.map
*.spec.*
SetupPackage.*
version.txt
```

I.e. unit tests (spec files) and typescript map files are ignored as well as the `SetupPackage.js` file and the `version.txt` file it creates. This leaves a clean package.

Finally the main `package.json` file has the following scripts for use by the build system (assumes `sh` is used as the shell).

```
"scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "prebuildpackage": "npm run clean && npm run compile && node dist/SetupPackage.js",
    "buildpackage": "cd dist && npm pack"
  },
```

To build the package the build system clones the repo, does `npm install` and then runs `npm run buildpackage` which in turn:

- Deletes the `dist` directory ensuring a clean compile.
- Compiles the typescript code to javascript.
- Executes the `SetupPackage.js` file which prepares `dist` for packaging.
- cds to the `dist` directory and builds the package there.

I use the `version.txt` file as an easy way to get the version in package.json and to tag my repo. There are countless other ways to do this or you may want to auto-increment the version. Remove this from `SetupPackage.ts` and `.npmignore` if it is not useful to you.

Comment: This answer looks like best one, but do you have ready solution aside theory?

Comment: @yumaa I've edited my answer with a concrete example. Hope it is useful.

Comment: Worked for me with some changes. Current `SetupPackage.ts` file copies files to `src` directory instead of `dist`. Thanks 

Comment: So... package.json in 99.9 percent of the open projects should not "check-in" package.json..?


The proper way to treat your package.json and everything in it is to make sure it does not contain secret/static values (such values should be provided by the CI as inputs / env vars etc...)

Comment: This is one of the best answers, With proper setups, you can configure them as you like this provides more control over npm pack.

Comment: We need an npm package for this.

Comment: This solution is great, but does not work with git repos.

Answer (score 23):

If your project has git you can use small hack.
Add next scripts to package.json

```
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build && cp -r ./lib/* . && rm -rf ./lib",
    "postpublish": "git clean -fd",
```

now when you run `publish` command npm involve `prepublishOnly`. It builds files and saves them to `lib` folder (a build script depend on your project). The next command copies files to root folder and removes `lib`.  After publish `postpublish` script returns the project to a previous state.

Comment: I'm a fan of this solution!

Comment: I really like this. The biggest problem with this solution is that if anything fails during prepare, prepack, pack, postpack, and publish, you're left with a bunch of stuff in your project root and you need to manually run `git clean -fd`.

Comment: this is a bad solution because source files will be involved in the published package

Comment: @Sheldeeb if you don't want to add some files you can just add something like `rm -rf ./src` to your prepublishOnly script.

Comment: I love this solution, it's perfect!

Answer (score 14):

```
cd TMPDIR
npm pack /path/to/package.json
```

The tarball will be created inside the TMPDIR directory.

Comment: ^This answer is underrated. `npm pack` plus the package.json `files` field (or `.npmignore`) works wonderfully.

Comment: How does this answer OP question ?

Answer (score 11):

I highly recommend you to use `.npmignore` instead of moving or copying things around, specially if you are using a CI for deployments, and just add there the files you don't want to publish.

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package

Example:

```
#tests
test
coverage

#build tools
.travis.yml
.jenkins.yml
.codeclimate.yml

#linters
.jscsrc
.jshintrc
.eslintrc*

#editor settings
.idea
.editorconfig
```

### **Update:**

If you want to split your code, into different npm packages using the same repo, I bumped into this project recently: [Lerna](https://lernajs.io/) and looks really good.

Maybe you should take a look

Comment: We would still have to emit our built files in the root directory of the package.  Perhaps permissible for CI.  Observe the post from Isaac's blog I linked to and tell me how your solution would allow for `require('mypackage/foo')` instead of `require('mypackage/dist/foo')`

Comment: I wasn't trying to solve that problem here. If you want to split your code, I bumped into this project recently: https://lernajs.io/ and looks really good

Comment: Found another tool that worth have a look :) https://github.com/philcockfield/msync

Comment: yeh material UI use it and i used this in. my last company, i found it ok

Answer (score 9):

### You need to publish the `dist` folder

The natural way to achieve that, according to the npm approach, is to publish the folder which is to be the root. There are several ways to do that, depends on the final environment you want to work with:

1. [npm publish <folder>](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/publish.html) from your package repo to an npm registry and then install your package in other project as you install other packages. In your case it would be `npm publish dist`.
2. [npm install <folder>](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/install.html) in some other project if you want to use your package only locally. In your case you go to the other project and run `npm install relative/path/to/dist`
3. [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/link.html) your folder locally to your `node_modules` in another project in case you'd like to have the changes in your original package reflected instantly in other project. In your case you first `cd dist` and run `npm link` and then go to the other project and run `npm link robsonrosa-ui-alert`.

**Prerequisite**: in any case above, prior to the publish/install/link, you have to put in your `dist` folder at least a proper `package.json` file. In your case, you have to have the package name defined in your package.json file as `"name": "robsonrosa-ui-alert"`. Typically, you'll want there also some other files like README.md or LICENSE.

**Remarks to methods 2 & 3**

Typically there are problems with package dependencies when you use the package installed this way. To avoid it, first pack the package with `npm pack dist` and then install the package in the target project from the packed tarball, i.e. `npm install path/to/package-tarball.tgz`.

**Automation example**

You can automate the publishing process using the [`prepare` script](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/scripts.html#life-cycle-scripts), combined with `build` script. Additionally, you can protect your package against an accidental publishing of the package root folder with [`"private": true`](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-json.html#private) field put in the package.json, located in the root directory of your package repo. Here is an example:

```json
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && gulp build && cat ./package.json | grep -v '\"private\":' > dist/package.json",
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
```

This way you won't publish the root folder and get the package built and package.json copied to the `dist` folder automatically, within the publishing process.

Comment: When I do `npm publish dist` it tries to push a package with the name `dist` instead of using the `dist` folder.

Comment: @Robin but have you done what I wrote in the **Prerequisite** section? I.e. have you copied the `package.json` to your `diist` folder?

Comment: `npm publish ./dist` works

Comment: @OneCricketeer, do you have .npmrc in your `/dist` folder?  I found that I was able to `npm publish ./dist`, as you suggested, but only when `.npmrc` is in the `dist` folder.

Comment: @OutstandingBill I don't think so since it's only the compiled JS files, but I do have one in the root of the project

Answer (score 4):

I have a Typescript project which compiles into a folder called `dist` and I have found a solution for Windows.

In my `package.json` at the root of my project:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepub": "copy package.json dist",
    "pub": "cd dist & npm publish",
    "postpub": "cd dist & del package.json"
  }
```

These scripts allow me to publish my `dist` folder as the root of my package by running `npm run pub`.

- `prepub` copies my package.json into the `dist` folder.
- `pub` changes the working directory to `dist/` and then runs `npm publish`
- `postpub` deletes `package.json` from my `dist` folder to ensure a clean publish every time.

This way, I can still have all the relevant configuration files in my project root but I can copy them to `dist` before publishing.

The same approach can probably work for Mac or Linux.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```sh
npm run build
cp package.json dist
cp .npmrc dist
cd dist
npm publish
```

I am using these commands from Jenkins to publish packages.

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple `package.json` solution:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
      "pack": "mkdir -p dist && cp package.json dist/package.json && npm pack ./dist",
      "pub": "npm publish $(node -p \"p=require('./package.json');p.name+'-'+p.version+'.tgz'\")"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this by doing the following:

1. I set my `package.json` as `private`. So I can not publish my package with `npm publish`
2. I create a `gulpfile` with the following steps:

```js
import gulp from 'gulp';
import shell from 'gulp-shell';
import replace from 'gulp-replace';

const compile = () => gulp.src('package.json').pipe(shell('npm run compile'));

const copy = () => gulp.src(['readme.md']).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

const update = () =>
  gulp.src('package.json').pipe(replace('"private": true,', '"private": false,')).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

const publish = () => gulp.src('package.json').pipe(shell('cd dist && npm publish'));

export default gulp.series(compile, copy, update, publish);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the directory you wish to publish. This is what I came up with for Typescript on Linux.

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepub": "rm -rf dist && tsc && cp package*.json dist",
    "pub": "npm publish ./dist"
  }
```

Thanks to @EnderShadow8 for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was similar but hairier at the same time since it involved publishing through a CI pipeline that was mostly out of my control, and which it and only it had publishing permissions through a `.npmrc` file it downloaded during its execution. And since it had to be shared with countless other teams and repositories, it had to be agnostic to the specifics of each repository.

After a lot of time wasted trying to copy over the `.npmrc` file to the npm's global root, which more often than not ended in permission warnings, trying to use different scripts in `package.json` which called upon the global npm instead and getting 403 HTTP errors, the solution finally dawned on me, and it couldn't be simpler if I tried.

All it took was including a shell script (could also be a batch file if the container ran Windows) in the application, checking for its existence in the pipeline and running it instead of `npm publish`.

Since nowadays the syntax `npm publish [folder]` exists, my script was pretty straightforward, but I can see how in different times it could have looked like  [@Eli Algranti's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076786/eli-algranti) script.

So here's how it looked in the end:

**publish.sh**

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
# THIS OVERRIDES THE DEFAULT PIPELINE PUBLISH SCRIPT TO BE RUN
# IT EXISTS SO ONLY THE BUILD OUTPUT FOLDER GETS PUBLISHED
npm publish ./dist
```

**npm-build.yml**

```
npm run build --if-present

if [ -f "./publish.sh" ]; then
  echo "'publish.sh' script has been found. Overriding the publishing with it"
  sh publish.sh
else
  npm publish
fi
```

This ran locally, with the current user and the `.npmrc` file that had already been copied, and could encapsulate a lot of other logic if necessary

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users, below is an example of how one might publish an package:

```
      "scripts": {
        "publish": "xcopy /y .npmrc dist && cd dist && npm publish"
      },
```

1. copy the .npmrc file (this defines the npm registry, such as https://npm.pkg.github.com and authorization token) into the distribution folder (e.g. dist)
2. change the directory into the distribution folder
3. run the standard `npm publish` process

To run the script from the command line:

```
     npm run publish
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one more approach which I think is the cleanest. It's all configuration based without needing to move files or specify paths in the build and pack scripts:

`package.json`
Specify the main file.

```
{
    "main": "lib/index.js",
}
```

Some additional typescript options:

- Specify the `rootDir`. This directory will have all the source code and it should have an `index` file in it (or some other file you can use as main in the `package.json`).
- Specify the `outDir`. This is where your tsc command will build to

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "lib",
    },
    ...

}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as what the OP originally had except changing the name from dist to lib?

Answer (score -2):

option 1: Navigate to the folder and execute "npm publish ." command

option 2: Run npm publish /path/directory

Answer (score -8):

Just create a **`.npmignore`** file  and add the following to it :

```
*.*
!dist/*
```

Comment: does this do as the OP requested? I wasn't able to get this to work. The idea was to make the published package contain only the contents of the dist directory without including the directory itself. I this to makes sure we don't include anything not in the dist directory which can already be done withe package.json "files" list.