# npm publish specify publish directory in package.json

Tags: npm

I am trying to streamline the NPM publish process by only having to run **npm publish** because sometime developers might forget to specify the publish directory. For instance I have the structure:

```
package.json
package
src
```

I'm building the package directory with regular npm scripts from /src then using the **prepublish** hook to copy the /package.json in the /package directory. What would be great is if I can specify the /package directory in package.json for it to be used as the package to be uploaded to NPM.

I know **npm publish ./package** works but developers forget this step and it also adds other files to the NPM repo that dont need to be there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to npm publish specific folder but as package root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935176/how-to-npm-publish-specific-folder-but-as-package-root)