# How to exclude the folder but include all of its files and sub-folder while npm publish in angular library

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When I build my angular library app i get the artifacts in the folder `dist/`. This means when the library is imported in another application it is done like this:

```
import { XXX } from 'libname/dist'
```

However, I would like the the import statement to be without dist folder. I can't change the directory from where the npm publish command is run so would like a solution (if possible) using .npmignore or package.json (files or main) properties.

Is this possible? The same question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935176/how-to-npm-publish-specific-folder-but-as-package-root) but I am not sure how to remove the dist folder and keep files/sub-folders in the package using npmignore, files and main properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your library must have this configuration in `angular.json` under `architect > options > project`:

```
"my-library": {
  "projectType": "library",
 ...
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
      "options": {
 ...
        "project": "projects/my-library/ng-package.json"
      },
 ...
```

And your ng-package.json file must be:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/my-library",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "umdModuleIds": {
    }
  }
}
```

Also you must have a `public-api.ts` file:

```
// public-api.ts
/*
 * Public API Surface of my-library
 */

export * from './lib/my-library.module';
...
```

Do you have all those files and configurations?

These are all configurations that should take place automatically when you create a library.
For reference you can watch:
https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

UPDATE:

"Currently I am copying my package.json into the dist folder and then running npm pack inside the dist folder."

With a gulp batch you can copy package.json from root to dist:

```
// /gulpfile.js 
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', [], function() {
  gulp.src(['../../my-library/package.json']) // pay attenction to your relative path where you run gulp.
      .pipe(gulp.dest('my-library/dist'));
});
```

To run it:

```
gulp default
```

In the gulp file directory.

And then try with `npm pack` in dist folder.

Comment: There files are all there. So once a build is run all files are generated into dist folder. I have a parent project with project.json file which is where npm pack is run. I copy the dist folder generated in the library to root path as dist/** but when npm run pack is initiated it takes dist folder also which is what i want to exclude.

Comment: Try with a gulp solution. I modified my answer to include an example of a gulp task.

Comment: AS i said before this is running via CI Jenkins file and I can't changed the location i.e. cd dist to run the npm pack. I can change the parent level package.json file or add npmignore file