# Remove dist from the import path

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, tsconfig, tsc

I wrote a small library

On `lib/index.ts` I have this code

```
export default function hello() {
    return 'world'
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "@org/library",
  "author": "Org name",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "clear": "rimraf dist/"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "exclude": ["lib/**/*.spec.tsx", "lib/**/*.stories.tsx", "lib/**/*.styles.tsx", "dist/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDirs": ["lib"],
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

But when I go to another project to use, I had to import using `dist` on the path

Why I had to import like this

```
import hello from '@org/library/dist'
```

And not

```
import hello from '@org/library'
```

What I need to do to remove `dist` from the import path?

Comment: May be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935176/how-to-npm-publish-specific-folder-but-as-package-root

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this that doesn't require publishing the npm module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended with a custom Makefile

```
.PHONY: build clean lint publish test

build:
    npm run build

clean:
    npm run clean

lint:
    npm run lint

test:
    npm run test

publish: clean lint test build
    cp package.json dist
    npm publish dist
```