# Node/NPM How to map import paths

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have an NPM module that uses another local NPM module containing shared code. Neither of them are public, this is all local.

I import the shared module in my package.json like so:

```
  "my-shared": "file:../my-shared-code"
```

When I npm install, my-shared-code gets imported correctly, and I can import code like:

```
import Blah from 'my-shared/src/sharedTypes';
```

### Problem

I have to use the word "src" in the import. However, when I build I create a `build` directory, which breaks all these imports!

I was wondering if I could use NPM to map the imports somehow?

Can I make it so I don't have to use the word "src" at all?

Could I just do:

```
import Blah from 'my-shared/sharedTypes';
```

and then it magically figures out whether to use the "src" or "build" dirs?

### What I tried

I looked into the options for `package.json`, and there is a "files" property that I thought might help. However I think that just whitelists files.

I also looked into the "main" property, however I'm not "exporting a module". I just have a load of utility files that I wanna be able to import into multiple other projects.

### What I'm actually trying to achieve

I'm using typescript, and I've got a front-end and a backend that both share types for certain models, but also share some utility functions.

I want my typescript/react front-end and my typescript backend to be able to import typescript files from another node_package, however it needs to know to use `"src"` for development and `"build"` when built for production.

Comment: You want to use the *build files* of the other module, not the source files. Typescript will happily consume the compiled JS of the shared module (esp if .d.ts declaration files are present).

Answer (score 0):

While it's not exactly what you're asking for, you might be looking for `npm link`.  It's not intuitive, but it's what I use for your above situation.

[`npm-link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link) is a way of registering local projects so that others can reference them.  Just beware that reading the docs is important -- using it may impact your local environment in non-obvious ways (especially if you build and publish directly from your machine--versus CI/CD).

Answer (score 0):

In the consumer project you can use path mapping --> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

As for the package, you can re-export using `export * from './my-file'` syntax, in a `index.ts` file (you may need one at each directory). But this is tedious if you have a lot of files. ([imperfect example](https://github.com/ambroiseRabier/ts-utils/blob/master/src/index.ts))

Another solution seems to make a script to copy the `package.json` into the dist folder and make the build there.

There is a similar discussion there: [How to npm publish specific folder but as package root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935176/how-to-npm-publish-specific-folder-but-as-package-root)